# cspack.exe and empty folders

Tags: azure, deployment

I have a question regarding **Azure** web role packages. I'm able to successfully create and deploy WebRoles using deploy packages for a while now. We use **cspack.exe** to create our package file.

Today, I have a problem with some empty folders in my sources, which are apparently not included in the package being created. These empty folders are mandatory (part of the CMS application, which requires those empty folders). Excluding those folders is not an option.

How can I **tell cspack.exe to include empty folders**?
The documentation on this utility is fairly limited [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/gg432988.aspx).

I can add a dummy file to include the empty folders I know, but this is not a solution as I don't know which other folders will be missing now (and in the future during CMS upgrades).

Comment: Starting to think there is just no way to do this, so unless I get an answer here, I will build my solution as "package as single file" and deploy my website on startup of the webrole with some power shell scripts. This way, cspack only has to take the entire zip package, not all files separately.

Comment: Can you give an example of the commandline you use with cspack?

Comment: This is an extract from the powershell script, which calls cspacke.exe: $cspack "$csdefFile" /out:$cspkgFile /rolePropertiesFile:$roleProperties

Comment: The current solution I implemented, is to 7zip the runtime folder of my site(s) and extract them automatically when the instance starts. This is working fine and has the advantage that the cspack.exe takes a lot less time.

Comment: I've been looking into the cspack code and mostly everything deals with files paths (not directories), which would make sense why your empty directories are not kept.  I'll let you know if I find a way around it ...

Comment: Can you generate dummy file in every empty folder under the certain root (CMS) in your powershell build script and delete dummy files in your role startup task

Comment: @AlexeyShcherbak : That would also be a valid work around. Yes it's possible.